# Can't use ldflags with bee pack command

Tags: go

I'm trying to compile beego with ldflags options:

```
bee pack -v -ba="-ldflags '-s -w'"
```

And go complains about it:

```
go build -o /var/folders/XXX/XXX/T/beePack-4329015000/XXXX -ldflags='-s -w'
invalid value "'-s" for flag -ldflags: missing =<value> in <pattern>=<value>
```

I'm using latest beego with go1.12.6. Looks like beego is separating the command line with `space` and added some checks.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

With -ldflags='-s -w'

```
GOOS=linux bee pack -v -exr=vendor -ba="-ldflags='-s -w'"
```

I got:

```
+ go build -o /var/folders/xxx/xxx/T/beePack-2277518000/xxx -ldflags='-s -w'
invalid value "'-s" for flag -ldflags: missing =<value> in <pattern>=<value>
```

Comment: Have you tried: `bee pack -v -ba="-ldflags='-s -w'" `?

Comment: @GiulioMicheloni see my update. Nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

I checked the source code of bee tool. It should be a bug and I would open an issue into their GitHub repo.

Here is the link to the relevant [code](https://github.com/beego/bee/blob/10bb0454f641a6dcf9ebc9ce9efcc89822586012/cmd/commands/pack/pack.go#L511). Please, take a look at the comments below.

```
    args := []string{"build", "-o", binPath}
    if len(buildArgs) > 0 {
        //Giulio: Here they split the input arguments using whitespace as delimiter.
        //In your case it would become: "-ldflags='-s -w'" => ["-ldflags='-s", "-w'"]
        args = append(args, strings.Fields(buildArgs)...)
    }

    if verbose {
        //Giulio: The print is fine, reconstruct the same string with strings.Join
        fmt.Fprintf(output, "\t%s%s+ go %s%s%s\n", "\x1b[32m", "\x1b[1m", strings.Join(args, " "), "\x1b[21m", "\x1b[0m")
    }
    //Giulio: but, here, they use the slice with splitted flags, i.e. ["-ldflags='-s", "-w'"], which is the real problem.
    execmd := exec.Command("go", args...)
```